# ASP.NET UpdatePanel Set value for Checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, updatepanel

I am using a ListView that contains a checkbox. I would like the checkbox to automatically update a bit field in my database from False to True (or visa versa) when the box is checked.

I am not familiar with the update panel and I'm struggling to find a way to achieve this.

My List View

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="NotificationID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">

    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <table runat="server" style="">
            <tr>
                <td>No notifications exist.<br /> NOTE: You must be logged in to see notificaitons</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr class="odd gradeX">
            <td><span style="display: none;"><%# ("00000000" + Eval("DateDescNumber")).TxtStrRight(8) %> - </span><%# GlobalUtilities.GetDiffDate(Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("DateTimeLogged"))) %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("UserName") %></td>
            <td><a href="<%# Eval("NotificationURL") %>"><%# Eval("NotificationTitle") %></a></td>
            <td class="center"><%# Eval("NotificationMessage") %></td>


            <td class="center">

                <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
                </asp:ScriptManager>

                <asp:updatepanel id="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxMarkedAsRead" runat="server" 
                                Checked='<%# Eval("MarkedAsRead") %>' 
                                AutoPostBack="true" 
                                Visible="true" 
                                Text =" Not Selelected"
                                oncheckedchanged="CheckBox_MarkedAsRead_CheckedChanged" />
                        </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:updatepanel>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>

    <LayoutTemplate>

        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="responsive dynamicTable display table table-bordered" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width:80px">Date</th>
                            <th>From</th>
                            <th>Notice</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th class="ch" style="width:53px;">Read</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>

</asp:ListView>
```

I have gone as far as creating the CheckBox_MarkedAsRead_CheckedChanged event in my Code behind (at least I think this is what I should do) but my attempts to script a solution in the code behind has been fail after fail.

Comment: I don't have any. Everything I have tried seems to fail. I can't get values from the Checkbox. I was hoping someone may have done this in the past and may have an example to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Of course people have done this in the past. But I can't tell you what you did wrong until you show me what you did. So show your code and I can probably help fix it, but I'm not going to write the whole thing from scratch for you. You don't learn as well that way. By the way, I'd ditch the update panel and code behind event handler in favor of AJAX and a Web API function to update the database. Much cleaner and easier on server resources.

Comment: Thanks Mason. I'll research how to do that.

Comment: That'll take you a bit of time to learn (though it's well worth it!), and I offered that as a longer term solution for a better architecture. But if you post your event handler from your code behind, we can probably get this update panel implementation working now.

Comment: I tried a few things but gave up and deleted it so I don't really have anything to show you now. I wasn't sure if I was even heading in the right direction as I am really new to this. Which is why I thought I would seek some advice here. But I appreciate your advice and it's clear I need to learn more. Thanks again.